# Suitable method for variable selection using random forest

Tags: random-forest

I am running a regression model using Random Forest and i would like to select a set of parsimonious predictors that can still achieve a good model performance. To this purpose, i have ran a a model selection routine that consists on two steps:
I first run a full model and rank the variables according to the importance, (i measure the importance as the decrease in accuracy). Secondly, i take the most important predictor from the full model and gradually added all the remaining ones, one at a time. By doing so, i see which predictor best improve modelling results base on an improvement on variance explain, thus building a new parsimonious model. I iteratively repeat this routine until no improvement of the variance explained by more than 2% could be achieved. I have read that a large number of variable RF selection methods are based on a decrease on the OOB-error more than by checking variance improvement, therefore i am not sure if i am chosing an suitable method. Could someone give an oppinion? Thank you

Comment: This are the variables for the full model ranked according to the %IncMSE :                                                                                 

ndvi 54,692
ndwi  53,953
Periodo_si 38,003
aet_max2 32,939
prc_m_spri 18,610
elev_cv 17,452
rugosidad 16,961
densi_05_2 16,924
deficit_sp 16,917
densi_2_4 14,874
total_all_r 12,570
densi_4_7 10,414
temp_m_ago 10,123
densi_mas7 9,392

Comment: i took the most important predictor from the full model and gradually added all the remaining ones, one at a time.                      

####RF ndvi alone (the most important variable of the full model)
  RFdatos16<-randomForest(formula=dnbr~ndvi, data=datos.fin5, mtry=1, importance=TRUE,  ntree=1000) 
  print(RFdatos16)
##output 
 Mean of squared residuals: 31188.07
                    % Var explained: 15.42944

Comment: ###########RF with NDVI plus each of the remaining predictors, starting with NDWI which is the second most important predictor ### RFdatos17<-randomForest(formula=dnbr~ndvi+ndwi, data=datos.fin5,
                        mtry=1,
                        importance=TRUE, 
                        ntree=1000)
RFdatos17                                                                                        
##output##                                                                                              Mean of squared residuals: 26384.37
                    % Var explained: 28.46

Comment: ####I continue testing the remaining predictor, in this case Periodo_si##RFdatos18<-randomForest(formula=dnbr~ndvi+Periodo_si, data=datos.fin5, mtry=1, importance=TRUE, ntree=1000)
print(RFdatos18)                                                                                        
##output##                                                                                              Mean of squared residuals: 24898.03
                    % Var explained: 32.49

Comment: #######after testing all the precitors, the one which most improves the variance explained was periodo_si, so i run a new model with ndvi+periodo_si and i repeat the process until no improvement of the variance explained by more than 2% could be achieved #####  RFdatos19<-randomForest(formula=dnbr~ndvi_deimo+Periodo_si+ndwi, data=datos.fin5,
                        mtry=1,
                        importance=TRUE, 
                        ntree=1000)
print(RFdatos19)

Comment: I hope this helps, thank you for answaring!!